# mailSender property is null in spring bean (both autowired and setter dont work)

Tags: spring, javabeans

I try to use mailsender to send email. To init mailSender, I tried to use @Service and @Autowired, it says mailSender is null; then I tried to use getter and setter, it says mailSender is null too.

I think this is probably a general spring bean question, but I followed online tutorials to set the property. What is wrong in my codes?

```
public class Test {
    private org.springframework.mail.MailSender mailSender;

    public org.springframework.mail.MailSender getMailSender() {
        return mailSender;
    }

    public void setMailSender(org.springframework.mail.MailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    public void send() {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();

        message.setFrom(MyFrom);
        message.setTo(MyTo);
        message.setSubject("test");
        message.setText("test");
        mailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

and following is my beans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />
    <bean id="validator"        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <property name="port" value="587" />
        <property name="username" value="username" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />

        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="mailMail" class="study.hard.Test">
         <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Following is class to call the test.send();

```
public class ProjectdMonitor { 
    public void alert() {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you verify? where is the method send() getting invoked? can you post the relevant code snippets

Comment: In my other class, I have an alert function (see the edit). I use Quartz in my project. The quartz job will call the alert() every hour.

Comment: you cannot do new Test(); ... spring is not aware of the new object so it does not do whatever you are expecting. Instead you must get your Test object with id "mailMail" from Spring application context and then invoke send()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using new operator to create bean and spring is not aware of this newly created bean. Therefore mailSender property will be null.

In the following code, we are getting the Test bean from spring application context instead of creating using new operator. As it is obtained from spring application context, all the autowiring happens.

Try the following:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
    Test test = context.getBean("mailMail", Test.class);
    test.send();
}
```